# Cant create a link to named routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to create a link to a named route

My routes.db have the following rule

```
match '/tablero', to: 'tablero#index',via: 'get' , as: 'tablero_main'
```

I can see the route using rake routes

```
tablero_main GET    /tablero(.:format)            tablero#index
```

But when i use the link_to as follows i get the "undefined local variable or method `tablero_main'" error.

```
<%= link_to "Tablero",tablero_main %>
```

Is there anything else i am missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to append `path` to the method name, like so:

```
<%= link_to "Tablero", tablero_main_path %>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Routes**

To help you further, you'll need to also consider the role of `resources` in your routes

As Rails uses a [resourceful routing infrastructure](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default), *every* route you create should be based around a resource. In your case:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :tablero, only: :index #-> domain.com/tablero
```

Admittedly, this will give you the path `tablero_index_path`, rather than `tablero_main_path`, but it ensures your routes are not only DRY, but also extensible. Nothing worse than having 100's of "`match` routes in a route file.

--

**Helpers**

After that, remember to use the correct `route_path` helper:

[image]

Each "route" path is basically just a helper method (which builds a URL for you). When using `link_to`, you need to reference the `path` helper directly. You didn't do this, which lead Rails to come back with the undefined method error